# rust thread and move keyword

Tags: rust, thread-safety

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

    let queue = Mutex::new(VecDeque::new());
    thread::scope(|s| {
    //let q_cl = queue
        let t = s.spawn(|| {
            loop{

                let item = queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front();
                if let Some(item) = item{
                    dbg!(item);
                }
                else{
                    thread::park();
                }
            }
        });

            for i in 1..{
                queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(i);
                t.thread().unpark();
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
             };
    });
}
```

I got this code from the book rust Atomics and Locks, from what I can understand a mutex is a datatype that does not implement copy trait so, so why is it that queue is not being borrowed by the first closure( I came to this conclusion because the queue is being used outside of the spawn function) and if it isn't being borrowed what exactly is occurring here.

Comment: Do you want `Arc<Mutex<VecDequeue>>`?

Answer (score 1):

> so why is it that queue is not being borrowed by the first closure( I came to this conclusion because the queue is being used outside of the spawn function) and if it isn't being borrowed what exactly is occurring here.

The queue *is* being borrowed by the first closure. But mutexes are one of the ways to implement inner mutability:

```
pub fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<'_, T>>
```

you only need a shared reference on the mutex to lock it.

So the `spawn`'s closure takes a shared reference, and the loop can still use the existing shared reference, they're not exclusive (hence *shared*).